# Using the same PC for two different activities in 2 diferent LAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, desktop-computer, computing-environment

I'm trying to find the best solution to use the same Windows 10 computers in PC labs for two different activities/scope that involve them to be part of two different LANs.

The organization where I am working is using two typologies of computers LABs:

- One is connected to the internal network (LAN) using standard software and configurations.
- The other is separated from the internal LAN and configured as an isolated environment and separate network (LAN) having different software and configurations as this LABS are used for different activities such as network penetration, Static IP manipulation etc ....

The purpose is to find a way for the students or users to choose (for example at the boot time) to use the same PCs for one or the other environment LAB.

On the second type of LABs there are differed needed and contraindications that are limiting me to find an ideal solution, so I would like to have if possible an exchange  of opinions with experts to investigate for the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The two setups seem contradictory, involving not only different settings
but also different installed software.

The solutions I can see are:

- Two partitions and two installations of Windows in dual-boot
- One installation as a virtual machine inside the other.